# Compile and run a coffeescript file on node.js on change

Tags: javascript, coffeescript

I am currently using this node.js command to watch coffeescript files for changes and compile them to a folder:

```
coffee -cwo ./js ./src
```

I wonder if there is a way to watch a folder/files for changes and if there is a change, run a compiled js file.

In this way I don't have to manually run "coffee file.coffee" each time I made a change in coffeescript files.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can either save the compiled JS *or* run it with a single `coffee` command, but not both. The command to run the `.coffee` files in `src` every time they change is simply

```
coffee -w src
```

For more complex compilation needs, you should write a Cakefile. Check out the one in sstephenson's [node-coffee-project](https://github.com/sstephenson/node-coffee-project/blob/master/Cakefile), for instance. That way, you can customize the whole compilation pipeline for your project's needs, e.g. compile -> run tests -> run the project if tests passed.

Comment: Actually that was really helpful. I run both commands and now when I change the CS files the ./js files will be changed, and when they are changed the other command is running the changed file.